# Android : on changing EditText background color, EditText style getting changed

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi When I change the Background color of `EditText` of two `EditText` they are looking like both merging.

My layout code goes like this `

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Text1"
    android:singleLine="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Text2"
    android:singleLine="true" >
</EditText>

<AutoCompleteTextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Text3"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Text4"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</LinearLayout>

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Button" />
```

`

and My Activity code goes like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText editText1, editText2, editText3, editText4;
Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.primary_text_dark_nodisable));
            editText3.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray));

        }
    });

}

private void init() {
    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

}
```

}

Refer the attached Screen shots below

Layout before clicking Button

[image]

Layout after clicking Button

[image]

Comment: Did you try 2 other colors to see the difference? I don't see them merging. I only see that the border is not visible anymore.

Comment: Thanks for comment @cosmincalistru, ya they are actually not merging but in view they look like merged. Its same effect with all colors. is there any solution for this

Answer (score 3):

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213449/removing-the-background-color-of-an-edittext) using `EditText.setBackgroundColor(any color)` will color your outline too. To keep the outline aspect i would recommend to include the edittext in a table row and use margin. Try this in your xml and see the result:

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:layout_margin="1dip"
        android:text="cosmincalistru" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Thanks for ans @cosmincalistru, I tried with TableLayout still the same result

Comment: Glad it helped. Anyway, good question, found something new 2day.

Answer (score -1):

You have set the same id for both the edittext. **@+id/editText2**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Text3"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Text4"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion nick, But the issue is not related with that, I tried correcting that still the same result