# Remove the background of a textview

Tags: android, background, textview

I set a background for a textview and I want to remove it dynamically but it dosen't work,
are there any suggestion?

```
if (mToday) {
        monthView[mRow][mColumn].setBackgroundResource(R.color.black);
    }
    else {
        monthView[mRow][mColumn].setBackgroundResource(0);
    }
```

I found a reasonable explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213449/removing-the-background-color-of-an-edittext) why it is happen, but again didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I checked all of the setbackgroundX methods but no one accept null!

Comment: textView.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
or 

    android:background="@null"

Comment: @Shiv I want to change it dynamically, can I change xml by code?

Comment: using tv.setBackgroundDrawable or setBackground color u can change it dynamically na??? remove background statement if any in xml

Comment: try myTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); or 
    t1.setBackgroundDrawable(null); or 

    t1.setBackgroundResource(0);

Comment: @Shiv none of them fix the problem...

Answer (score 12):

try this.

```
txtEmail.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Comment: You sure? because it normally helps, remember it has to be background**Resource**

Answer (score 5):

try the following code just changed 0 to null in **.setBackgroundDrawable** thats all it will work check once :

```
 if (mToday)
 {
     monthView[mRow][mColumn].setBackgroundResource(R.color.black);
 }
else
 {
      monthView[mRow][mColumn].setBackgroundDrawable(null);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this should work

`monthView[mRow][mColumn].setBackgroundDrawable(null);`